# 'D' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: json, swift

I'm facing below issue in Swift 4.2 with Xcode 10

[image]

I'm creating all the model classes. The API response contains this type of JSON Object:

```
{  
   "d":{  
      "results":[  
         {  
            "__metadata":{  
               "id":"urls"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I create classes with the same name without ambiguity?

Here is my class implementation:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class SearchPINModel: Codable {
    let d: D?

    init(d: D?) {
        self.d = d
    }
}

class D: Codable {
    let results: [Result]?

    init(results: [Result]?) {
        self.results = results
    }
}

class Result: Codable {
    let metadata: Metadata?
    let sapID, deviceID, mobileNo, employeeName: String?
    let pincode, sapUser, deviceCode: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metadata = "__metadata"
        case sapID = "SapId"
        case deviceID = "DeviceId"
        case mobileNo = "MobileNo"
        case employeeName = "EmployeeName"
        case pincode = "Pincode"
        case sapUser = "SapUser"
        case deviceCode = "DeviceCode"
    }

    init(metadata: Metadata?, sapID: String?, deviceID: String?, mobileNo: String?, employeeName: String?, pincode: String?, sapUser: String?, deviceCode: String?) {
        self.metadata = metadata
        self.sapID = sapID
        self.deviceID = deviceID
        self.mobileNo = mobileNo
        self.employeeName = employeeName
        self.pincode = pincode
        self.sapUser = sapUser
        self.deviceCode = deviceCode
    }
}

class Metadata: Codable {
    let id, uri: String?
    let type: String?

    init(id: String?, uri: String?, type: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.uri = uri
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post *code,* not screen shots.

Comment: The error message “invalid redeclaration” indicates that there is something else (not shown here) which causes the problem. We need a [mcve].

Comment: your code compiles may be you declare something similar to D

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F, type `D` and press ↩ to find the other declaration of `D`. A more descriptive name than a single letter would make the search more efficient. 

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let d: D
}

struct D: Codable {
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let metadata: Metadata

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metadata = "__metadata"
    }
}

struct Metadata: Codable {
    let id: String
}
```

Comment: No. It gives error "Invalid redeclaration of 'D'" if I create the struct.

Comment: replace all your models to what in answer

Comment: look if you declare other type of D even it's a class / struct

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your intention, but to create two classes with same name, you have to embed them in some parent, and then reference them like this, to remove ambiguity.

this code print 3 and then "blah"

```
import Foundation

class A {
    class D {
        let property = 3
    }
}

class B {
    class D {
        let property = "blah"
    }
}

class C {
    let d1 = A.D()
    let d2 = B.D()
}

let c = C()
print(c.d1.property)
print(c.d2.property)
```